# React Set Class Active when it is checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set an `active class` when the Card is checked, i do not know what i am doing wrong.

This is my scenario

```
const handleCardClick = (index) => {
  const newFiles = files.map((file, i) => {
    if (i === index) file.checked = !file.checked
    return file
  });
}

<MediaCard
  onClick={() => handleCardClick(i)}
  checked={file.checked}
  className={`Card-${file.checked > 0 ? "active" : "notActive"}`}
/>
```

This is how i am trying

```
className={`Card-${file.checked > 0 ? "active" : "notActive"}`}
```

It looks it is not working like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your variable directly like this:

```
className={`Card-${!!file.checked ? "active" : "notActive"}`}
```